Converting ARM assembly to RISC-V assembly
I am trying to rewrite this code. It works perfectly for ARM assembly, but I am trying to rewrite it in RISC-V assembly. Here is the ARM code:
.text
.global main

.equ ADD1, 0x40000000
.set ADD2, 0x40000004

main:
    ldr r1,=ADD1
    ldr r2,=ADD2
loop:
    ldr r0,[r1]
    str r0,[r2] 
    b loop      

.end

My best attempt is:
.global main

.data
ADD1: .word 0x40000000
ADD2: .word 0x40000004

.text
main:
    la  t0, ADD1 
    lw  a1, 0(t0)    
    la  t1, ADD2     
    sw  a1, 0(t1)    
    j main           

.end


But when I try and build it in Vitis, I get the following errors:
../src/PROJ1.S:9: Error: register expected, but saw 't0,ADD'
../src/PROJ1.S:9: Error: register expected, but saw '0,ADD1'
../src/PROJ1.S:9: Fatal error: missing operand
make: *** [src/subdir.mk:23: src/PROJ1.o] Error 1

I cannot seem to find any assistance for the first two errors. How do I fix all of these particular issues?

Try to use a li instruction instead.

.equ and .set are used to define compile-time constants (i.e. to associate a name with a value for use by the remainder of the source being assembled), they don't create runtime storage or program global variables — whereas .word defines (initialized) storage (that when in .data is mutable), i.e. global variables.  Runtime variables and compile-time constants are not really the same thing.  You might be able to use .equ or .eqv or some other to achieve the same compile-time constant definition in RISC V.

A global variable has an address & a value, whereas a constant (which is not stored in program memory) has no address, only a value.  You can use initialized global variables, but they have to be loaded (as we do with variables) to obtain their values (they are not constants, but their addresses in program memory are constant). The pseudo instruction la is for obtaining the address of a global variable, so a further dereference is required to obtain a global variable's value.

li t0, ADD1 is a drop-in replacement for ldr r1,=ADD1.  Keep the .equ the same.  You can optimize the the setup of the second constant to add t1, t0, 4 because of the values of those specific constants, the first being constructible with one lui, and the second being constructible from that since it's within +- 2^11

The toolchain you have used is not the correct one for this particular version of Assembly.
On Vitis Classic: Right click on the application icon, go into C/C++ settings and change the toolchain to the correct assembly language.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
